# ! Undefined control sequence. <argument>

Tags: xetex, algorithm2e, xepersian

but it has a error. please help me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}
\setdigitfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand*{\listalgorithmcfname}{فهرست الگوریتم ها} % used for list of algorithms
\renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{الگوریتم}      % used for title
\renewcommand*{\algorithmautorefname}{االگوریتم} % used for autoref
\begin{algorithm}[H]

\begin{flushright}
\begin{persian}
 \caption{اضافه کردن به history table}

\end{persian}
\end{flushright}
\begin{flushleft}

\begin{latin}
\While{TTl>0}{
select Ni\;
NbR =  Neighbors Of (Ni)\;
j=count of (NbR)\;
TTl = TTL - 1\;
\While{j<>0}{
send query to NbRj\;
n= Number Of Row (history\_t\_NbRj)\;
n=n+1\;
history\_t\_NbRj(n).Msg\_ID=Msg\_ID\;
history\_t\_NbRj(n).Node\_ID=Ni.ID\;
\eIF {search for find Msg\_ID in history\_t\_NbRj }
{del connection between Ni,NbRj\;
del Row (history\_t\_NbRj(n))\;
}
}
  \eIF  {TTL <>0 \textbf{OR} response not find}{
   Ni=NbR\;
   }{
   end\;
 }
}
\end{latin}
\end{flushleft}


\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

The error:

```
*************************************************
* fontspec warning: "rename-feature-not-exist"
* 
* The feature Renderer doesn't appear to be defined.
*************************************************
)) (./inert_history.aux) (c:/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...y\_t\_NbRj(n).Node\_ID=Ni.ID\; \eIF 
                                                  {search for find Msg\_ID i...
l.46 }
      ?
```

Comment: I haven't used `algorithm2e` for a long time but: shouldn't it be `\eIf` (capital "`I`", small "`f`")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two `else-if` statements, but there are no `if` statements.
The first `eIF` should be `If`. And I think the second one also should be `If`.
Also pay attention to the lowercase f in both `\If` and `\eIf`.
By the way, there is no need in using `flushright` or `flushleft` and `XePersian` fix all this automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ruled,lined]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}
\setdigitfont{XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}


\renewcommand*{\listalgorithmcfname}{فهرست الگوریتم ها} % used for list of algorithms
\renewcommand*{\algorithmcfname}{الگوریتم}      % used for title
\renewcommand*{\algorithmautorefname}{االگوریتم} % used for autoref
\begin{algorithm}[H]

\begin{persian}
 \caption{اضافه کردن به history table}

\end{persian}

\begin{latin}
\While{TTl>0}{
select Ni\;
NbR =  Neighbors Of (Ni)\;
j=count of (NbR)\;
TTl = TTL - 1\;
\While{j<>0}{
send query to NbRj\;
n= Number Of Row (history\_t\_NbRj)\;
n=n+1\;
history\_t\_NbRj(n).Msg\_ID=Msg\_ID\;
history\_t\_NbRj(n).Node\_ID=Ni.ID\;
\If {search for find Msg\_ID in history\_t\_NbRj }
{del connection between Ni,NbRj\;
del Row (history\_t\_NbRj(n))\;
}
}
  \eIf  {TTL <>0 \textbf{OR} response not find}{
   Ni=NbR\;
   }{
   end\;
 }
}
\end{latin}

\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

[image: Output]